# Is it possible to use an extension cable to wire iPhone Touch ID to logic board directly?

Tags: iphone, hardware, touch-id

I have an old iPhone 8, that during one repair attempt, I ripped apart the flex cable that connects the Touch ID. The broken part is the segment that comes out from the screen back and connects to the logic board. See picture (not the actual piece) below that marks which flex cable I broke.

The original Touch ID itself (incl. its short wire that connects to the back of the screen) is still intact.

[image: Broken wire]

What I found:

1. There are people selling "extension cables" like [this one](https://www.ebay.com/itm/304110176135?chn=ps&_trkparms=ispr%3D1&amdata=enc%3A1C2u-Tw58RneNOZv2JEMU-Q54&norover=1&mkevt=1&mkrid=711-117182-37290-0&mkcid=2&mkscid=101&itemid=304110176135&targetid=1584571731043&device=c&mktype=&googleloc=9032154&poi=&campaignid=15275224983&mkgroupid=131097072938&rlsatarget=pla-1584571731043&abcId=9300697&merchantid=459451172&gclid=CjwKCAjw8-OhBhB5EiwADyoY1cO0K1Ef6QSfI9QJCqu-iGF0AlJlb4B9wqG1Eds79pret9dgr7IV6xoCxIwQAvD_BwE), but this one explicitly says that it does not have Touch ID functionality.
2. There are some other similar listing that do not say whether it actually make Touch ID work or not.
3. There are several posts like [this one](https://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/453395/Home+button+extension+cable+replacement) I can find online that says this cable cannot be replaced.

I have the option to replace the screen as a whole and keep my original Touch ID, however the replacement screen misses 3D Touch, True Tone, and color range also seems worse than the original piece.

I understand only the original Touch ID could work with the original logic board if I don't let Apple fix this. My Touch ID is still good. I'd like to know what role does the screen (or the Touch ID cable part that is hidden inside the screen back) play in the Touch ID validation.

Comment: This is info you need to get from the cable supplier or manufacturer- we can’t speak to their cables functionality.  No, speaking pragmatically here, the cable plays no part in TouchID other than sending signals, if the cable apple uses has extra pins or a slightly different configuration than a standard display to accommodate TouchID, then it won’t work. Again, this needs to be answered by the cable supplier.

Comment: @Allan Basically your answer to the original question is "yes, it is possible". My understanding of your statement is that a specific vendor might produce wires that are not able to achieve this, but Apple itself did not put any validation/requirement on the wire, that prevents this usage. It could be an answer instead of a comment. Thanks.

Comment: I’m hesitant to do so because I can’t confirm the pin configuration of the original Apple cable.  Apple has been known to embed additional signals “on the wire” so to speak (like the power button and keyboard).  It might be that voltage isn’t passed to the TouchID sensor or that whatever signaling isn’t used is because the pins are not quite right.

Comment: For me, it’s ultimately about getting accurate  answers first; points second

Comment: @Allan Thanks for trying to be accurate. I guess then I do not have an answer until someone (or myself) actually gets this working. Only issue is that I already spent quite a lot on this old phone and buying another $10 cable and waiting for several days for it to arrive is quite tiring, especially if I do not know whether it is going to work or not. :-|